# Build fails because of closure type

Tags: swift, closures

I have a problem with closure in my function. I try to sort array from UserDefault. When I try to use "let topScoreSorted = userDefaultsArray.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }" build fails with error "Unable to infer closure type in the current context". How can I fix this?

```
func addScoreToUserDefault(with key: String, and value: Int) {

    // UserDefaults array
    var userDefaultsArray = defaults.dictionary(forKey: "TopScore")!

    let topScoreSorted = userDefaultsArray.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }

    // checks if name exists in userDefault array and if value is higher than in origin
    for n in 0...3 {

        if topScoreSorted[n].key == key && topScoreSorted[n].value <= value {
            userDefaultsArray.removeValue(forKey: topScoreSorted[n].key)
            userDefaultsArray[key] = value
        }
    }

    // check if array has more than 5 elements and if value is higher than origin, if true removes last value and add higher one
    if topScoreSorted.count >= 5 && topScoreSorted[0].value <= value {
        userDefaultsArray.removeValue(forKey: topScoreSorted[0].key)
        userDefaultsArray[key] = value

    } else if topScoreSorted.count < 5 {
        userDefaultsArray[key] = value
    }

    let sortedArray = userDefaultsArray.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }

    defaults.set(userDefaultsArray, forKey: "TopScore")
}
```

Comment: You can explain to the compiler what content you have in your array, that I assume isn't an array but a dictionary or...?, like `var userDefaultsArray: [String: Int]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userDefaultsArray` is of type `[String:Any]` and when you're comparing `$0.1 < $1.1` who knows what type the `values` are?

You're trying to compare `Any` type of values which can be anything. It can be a `String` or an `Int` or may be a `Double`.

When using `Any`, you need to typecast the variable to a particular type or specify the `Dictionary` type in the start itself.

**Example 1** : typecasting the `value`

```
let topScoreSorted = userDefaultsArray.sorted {
    if let value1 = $0.1 as? Int, let value2 = $1.1 as? Int {
        return value1 < value2
    }
    return false
}
```

**Example 2** : specifying the `Dictionary` Type

```
var userDefaultsArray = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "TopScore") as! [String:Int]
let topScoreSorted = userDefaultsArray.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
```